# For any values $(a_{ij})$, $i, j = 1, \ldots, N$, are there numbers $(x_l)$ such that $\frac{x_i}{x_j} = a_{ij}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we find $N$ real numbers $x_1, x_2,...,x_N$ such that $x_i/x_j=a_{ij}$ for any set of values for $a_{ij}$? It seems unlikely but I am particularly interested in the positive case. Also, it is clearly true in the positive case for N equal to 2 and 3.

Comment: You have $a_{ij} = x_i/x_j = 1/(x_j/x_i) = 1/a_{ji}$, so it is not possible for all values of $a_{ij}$ even if $N = 2$.

Comment: Are you asking whether or not given an assignment of values for the $a_{ij}$ we can find the $x$'s that satisfy this ratio?  If so, then it is not true in the case $N=2$.  Whenever $a_{11}$ differs from 1, you cannot find values for $x$'s that satisfy the ratio.

Comment: Im on a mobile device for please forgive the brevity of the question. The question I am asking is if we can find for example, x, y, z such that all unique ratios up to inverses, x/y=a, y/z=b, x/z=c, for any a,b,c. Then the question extrapolates to N variables. With further examination the answer seems to be no.

Comment: Note that you have $N^2$ of the $a_{ij}$ and only $N\ x$'s.  You are trying to solve $N^2$ equations in $N$ unknowns.  This usually fails.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not, even for $N = 2$: For any $(x_i)$ that satisfy the criterion we must have $$a_{ii} = \frac{x_i}{x_i} = 1$$ and
$$a_{ij} a_{ji} = \frac{x_i}{x_j} \frac{x_j}{x_i} = 1 .$$ So, for $N = 2$, we conclude that there is a solution iff
$$
\pmatrix{1 & a^{-1} \\ a & 1}
$$
for some $a \in \Bbb R^{\ast}$.

Similarly (for general $N$) we must have
$$a_{i_1 a_2} a_{i_2 i_3} \cdots a_{i_{k - 1} i_k} a_{i_k i_1} = 1$$ for all $k$ and $i_1, \ldots, i_k$. (Possibly these conditions together generate all of the conditions on the $(a_{ij}$ necessary for existence of a solution.)

Generically, we should not expect there to be any solutions when we specify more than $N$ constraints on $N$ variables.